# nginx proxy_pass and URLs in page

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have problem with proxy_pass in nginx. I have one page, for example test.com. In test.com/article I use proxy_pass:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    test.pl;
    root           /var/www/html/test.com;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;

        location /article/ {
                proxy_pass https://anotherpage.com/;
        }

}
```

And it's work, but if I have links in page test.com/article, they look like: test.com/some-link

I want it would be: test.com/article/some-link

Any ideas or tips how can I do that?

Comment: You are supposed to generate that links by yourself. It’s really unclear what do you mean exactly...

Comment: @emix ok, so I try explain. I have two sites. And I want second site in first site:
test.com/help = anotherpage.com (so first page contains second page :))
but when I have links in test.com/help (it's anotherpage.com because of proxy_pass) they direct to test.com/some-link instead of test.com/help/some-link